# MongoDB - Collection lacks a unique index on _id

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB server running on version 2.0.6. I set up a replicaset with a new server with version 2.6.3.

After finalizing the replication configuration (which is working properly), every time I log on the secondary server, I have the following warning:

```
2014-07-31T12 :08:40.666-0300 [initandlisten] WARNING: the collection 'xxx.yyy' lacks a unique index on _id. This index is needed for replication to Function Properly 
2014-07-31T12 :08:40.666-0300 [initandlisten] To fix this, you need to create a unique index on _id. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/build-replica-set-indexes
```

I have no idea about it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: you are replicating between a 2.0.6 server and a 2.6.3 server?

Comment: Yes, I'm replicating between this.

Comment: Note: as per the startup warnings, you need to ensure a unique index for for the collection `xxx.yyy`, eg `use xxx; db.yyy.ensureIndex({_id:1})`. Versions of MongoDB older than 2.2 allowed you to create capped collections without an `_id` index, which results in slow replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.0 and 2.6 are not compatible with each other in a replica set. Please upgrade the 2.0 server incrementally to 2.2, then 2.4, then 2.6. 2.4 will be the [first version compatible with 2.6](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6-upgrade/#upgrade-replica-set) in a replica set. You can find upgrade instructions for all version increments of 0.2 (e.g. 2.2 -> 2.4) in the [release notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/) sections of the docs.