# Make _id index unique in a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I recently saw this error in a Mongo 2.6 replicaset:

```
WARNING: the collection 'mydatabase.somecollection' lacks a unique index on _id. This index is needed for replication to function properly.
```

I assumed the _id index would be unique by default. But I am trying to check / set it. getIndexes shows there is no unique option set.

```
> db.somecollection.getIndexes()[0]
{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
                "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "mydatabase.somecollection",
        "name" : "_id_"
}
> db.somecollection.ensureIndex({"_id":1},{unique:true})
> { "numIndexesBefore" : 3, "note" : "all indexes already exist", "ok" : 1 }
> db.somecollection.getIndexes()[0]
{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
                "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "mydatabase.somecollection",
        "name" : "_id_"
}
```

I have tried `.validate(true)`:

```
...
    "valid" : true,
    "errors" : [ ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

and also `.reIndex()` that runs without error. I am unable to remove the _id index to recreate it - how can I set the index to unique or what should I do to ensure data consistency in the RS? Note the RS was upgraded as per upgrade instructions from 2.2 --> 2.4 --> 2.6. I have found this [MongoDB - Collection lacks a unique index on _id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25166898/mongodb-collection-lacks-a-unique-index-on-id) but there is nothing that resolves my issue in there.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this in the past when a new member to the replica set was added with a different Compatibility Version.  Run db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } ) on all of your nodes in the replica set and if one is different, stop the replication on that node, change the CompatibilityVersion and then ready it to the replica.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that the error came up when a new member was added to the existing replica set, and was only shown on that member. If I connect to the database and try add a duplicate _id, I get the usual `E11000 duplicate key error index: ...` even though `getIndexes()` doesn't indicate the unique constraint on the index (assuming it is implicit).